# Check if the series with $a_n = \frac{1}{n(\mathrm{ln}n)^p(\mathrm{lnln}n)^q}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

There's the following:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{n(\mathrm{ln}n)^p(\mathrm{lnln}n)^q} \hspace{1mm} (n > 2)$$

Therefore I converted it to the proper series:

$$\sum_{x=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(\mathrm{ln}x)^p(\mathrm{lnln}x)^q} $$

As I can judge it can be checked using integral test:

$$\int_{3}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x(\mathrm{ln}x)^p(\mathrm{lnln}x)^q}$$

therefore:

$$\mathrm{ln}x = t \Rightarrow dt = \frac{dx}{x}$$

$$\int_{ln3}^{n} \frac{dt}{t^p(\mathrm{ln}t)^q}$$

How can I take this integral with respect of $t$ and $q$ ?

Comment: You don't need to evaluate the integral to test for convergence.

Comment: You may also have a look at the Cauchy condensation test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\text{ converges } \iff
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n a_{2^n}\text{ converges}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy for $\sum a_n$ is surely to do the case $a_n=\frac{1}{n (\ln n)^p}$ first by the Integral Test, and get Conv for $p>1$ and Divergent for $p\leqslant 1$. (Maybe you've done that in class?)

Now consider the case $a_n=\frac{1}{n (\ln n)^p (\ln\ln n)^q}$.

For $p>1$ and $p<1$ we can use comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^{p_0}}$ where $p>p_0>1$ or $p<p_0<1$ as case may be; the $\ln\ln n$ term can be "absorbed" into the little bit of leeway we have given ourselves.

So the remaining case is when $p=1$, and here we just use the Integral Test straight, changing variable to $\ln \ln x$.